# How can I Send Java List in JSON response with key and value

Tags: java, json, spring-mvc

I am using spring mvc architecture. And when I fire query I am getting following in result.
But I want key-value pair in result. My result:

```
  {
   "searchResult":
   [
       [
           "hiteshp",
           121231,
           "Hitesh",
           "Patel",
           3,
           4,
           "false",
           "false",
           "GratZeez",
           23
       ],
       [
           "hiteshp",
           121231,
           "Hitesh",
           "Patel",
           3,
           4,
           "false",
           "false",
           "TGB",
           23
       ]
   ],
   "isError": "0",
   "message": "Search completed."
}
```

But i want the response to look like this

```
{
   "searchResult":
   [
       [
           "userName":"hiteshp",
           "contactNo":121231,
           "firstName":"Hitesh",
           "lastName":"Patel",
           "avgRate":3,
           "userId":4,
           "shareRate":"false",
           "isImage":"false",
           "oName":"GratZeez",
           "oId":23
       ],
    "isError": "0",
   "message": "Search completed."
}
```

My code is for  firing query is:

```
List<Map<String, Object>> objUserMasterList = null;
Map<String, Object> objMapUserMasterList = null;

objUserMasterList = (List<Map<String, Object>>)      this.commonService.getDataBySQLQuery(UserMaster.class, qStringUser,objMapProperties);

objMapUserMasterList.put("searchResult", objUserMasterList);
responseData.putAll(objMapUserMasterList);
```

Comment: Please give more detail. What is `responseData`? What is your class `UserMaster`?

Comment: You can't get your desired result, it's not valid JSON. Objects have key value pairs, not arrays. You're also missing a closing `]` somewhere in there.

Comment: i know its not valid json but i want results in key-value pair that's why i have post my code and suggest me how to get key-value pair in result or how to send key-value pair to front end.

Comment: responseData is the object of JSONObject                      JSONObject responseData = new JSONObject();                                  and UserMaster is the POJO class or model of spring mvc